# NameError: name 'regc' is not defined in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I got a name error when i am using this code.Can anyone fix this problem?

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector

home=Tk()
home.geometry("700x700")
home.title("Home")

reg=Button(home,text="Register",bg='brown',fg='white',width=20,command=regc)
reg.place(x=350,y=200)
mainloop()
```

I got an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Softech/Desktop/tkinterproject.py", line 29, in <module>
 reg=Button(home,text="Register",bg='brown',fg='white',width=20,command=regc)
 NameError: name 'regc' is not defined
```

Comment: `regc` should be a function that is known to the script (maybe defined somewhere else or imported)

Comment: You said `command=regc` and now python is looking for a function named `regc` to execute when the button is clicked, but no such button exists, so how will it work, you have to start by `def regc():` in the code and add its functionalities

Comment: def regc():

    global g
    global a
    global ph
    global blood_txt
    global rh_txt
    
    root=Toplevel()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    root.title("Registration")
   
    Label_reg=Label(root,text="REGISTRATION FORM",width=20,font=("bold",20))
    Label_reg.place(x=90,y=53)

Comment: I defined the function but i get the error

Comment: Putting a bunch of code in the comments is unhelpful. Post a [mre] in your question.

Comment: I am sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to define the function `regc`, anyway in the code its not there. So start off by defining it. Keep in mind, you have to define it before the declaration of the button.

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector

def regc():
    new=Toplevel()
    new.geometry("500x500")
    new.title("Registration")
    Label_reg=Label(new,text="REGISTRATION FORM",width=20,font=("bold",20)) 
    Label_reg.place(x=90,y=53)
    lname=Label(new,text="Name",width=20,font=("bold",10)) 
    lname.place(x=80,y=130)

home=Tk()
home.geometry("700x700")
home.title("Home")

reg=Button(home,text="Register",bg='brown',fg='white',width=20,command=regc)
reg.place(x=350,y=200)
home.mainloop()
```

To understand more on how to define a function, take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm#:%7E:text=Defining%20a%20Function,be%20placed%20within%20these%20parentheses.)

Hope it helped you solve your error.

Cheers

Comment: I defined the function like this:      def regc():

    global g
    global a
    global ph
    global blood_txt
    global rh_txt
    
    root=Toplevel()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    root.title("Registration")
    
    Label_reg=Label(root,text="REGISTRATION FORM",width=20,font=("bold",20))
    Label_reg.place(x=90,y=53)

    lname=Label(root,text="Name",width=20,font=("bold",10))
    lname.place(x=80,y=130)

Comment: I don't know.When i run this code ,it shows name error like i mentioned above

Comment: It works.Instead of defining 'regc' function above 'home=Tk()' , I defined it below 'home.mainloop()'.   Thanks  Cool Cloud